# How to use Table-Valued User-Defined Function to fill another table columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

*Hi I managed to create a function which I found in here.I need to fill the data of this Element column to another table columns.I don't seems to find a way Can you take a look at my huge problem.*

```
   ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[func_Split] 
    (   
    @DelimitedString    varchar(8000),
    @Delimiter              varchar(100) 
    )
RETURNS @tblArray TABLE
    (
    ElementID   int IDENTITY(1,1),  -- Array index
    Element     varchar(1000)               -- Array element contents
    )
AS
BEGIN

-- Local Variable Declarations
-- ---------------------------
DECLARE @FinaLResult varchar(max)
DECLARE @Index      smallint,
                @Start      smallint,
                @DelSize    smallint

SET @Delimiter = '='

SET @DelSize = LEN(@Delimiter)

-- Loop through source string and add elements to destination table array
-- ----------------------------------------------------------------------

WHILE LEN(@DelimitedString) > 0
BEGIN

    SET @Index = CHARINDEX(@Delimiter, @DelimitedString)


    IF @Index = 0 
        BEGIN

            INSERT INTO
                @tblArray 
                (Element)
            VALUES
                (LTRIM(RTRIM(@DelimitedString)))             

            BREAK


   END


  ELSE IF @Delimiter = '='
  BEGIN

  INSERT INTO
                    @tblArray 
                    (Element)
                VALUES
                    (SUBSTRING(@DelimitedString,CHARINDEX('=',@DelimitedString)+1,(CHARINDEX('&',@DelimitedString)-(CHARINDEX('=',@DelimitedString)+1))))
            SET @Delimiter='&'

  END

    ELSE 
        BEGIN

            INSERT INTO
                @tblArray 
                (Element)
            VALUES
                (LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(@DelimitedString, 1,@Index - 1))))

                --(RIGHT((LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(@DelimitedString, 1,@Index - 1)))),LEN((LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(@DelimitedString, 1,@Index - 1)))))-CHARINDEX('=',(LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(@DelimitedString, 1,@Index - 1)))))))

            SET @Start = @Index + @DelSize
            SET @DelimitedString = SUBSTRING(@DelimitedString, @Start , LEN(@DelimitedString) - @Start + 1)             

            SET @DelimitedString=(RIGHT(@DelimitedString,LEN(@DelimitedString)-CHARINDEX('=',@DelimitedString)))


            --SET @Delimiter='&'

            END

END

RETURN
```

END

*This is how I use the function but which wasn't the way I want*

```
 DECLARE @SQLStr varchar(MAX)
SELECT @SQLStr = 'CountryName=UK&Status=Success&QueryID=232919474&NetworkCode=23430&Organisation=mobile'

SELECT
    *
FROM
    dbo.func_split(@SQLStr, '&')
```

*And I wrote a Stored procedure as well.I'm using this SP to call the function and fill the columns of tbl_HLRProceeData table.*

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[HLRProcessTableFilled] ON [dbo].[tbl_CRM_TempResult]
AFTER INSERT
AS
    --DECLARE @TaskID INT = 0

-- DECLARE @i INT = 1

-- DECLARE @count INT

 DECLARE @TempResultID int
 DECLARE @HLRResult varchar(max)
 DECLARE @QueryID VARCHAR(max)


SET @HLRResult = '';
SET @QueryID = '';




IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT QueryID 
              FROM [WebReg].[dbo].[tbl_HLR_ProcessedData]
              WHERE QueryID = @QueryID)



DECLARE @ProcessedDataHeaderID int
DECLARE @UploadExcelDetailID int
DECLARE @Status varchar(100)
DECLARE @MobileCountry varchar(75)
DECLARE @MobileCountryISO varchar(50)
DECLARE @MobileNetwork varchar(100)
DECLARE @NetType varchar(50)
DECLARE @MobileNetworkCode varchar(50)
DECLARE @Location varchar(50)
DECLARE @ErrorCode varchar(10)
DECLARE @ErrorDescription varchar(100)
DECLARE @Ported bit
DECLARE @PortedFrom varchar(100)
DECLARE @PortedFrom2 varchar(100)
DECLARE @FileRefId int
DECLARE @CheckDate datetime
DECLARE @CreateUserId int
DECLARE @MSISDN varchar(20)
DECLARE @Organisation varchar(1000)


BEGIN
                INSERT INTO [WebReg].[dbo].[tbl_HLR_ProcessedData]
               ([ProcessedDataHeaderID],
                [UploadExcelDetailID]      
               ,[QueryID]
               ,[HlrStatus]
               ,[MobileCountry]
               ,[MobileCountryISO]
               ,[MobileNetworkCode]
               ,[MobileNetwork]
               ,[NetType]
               ,[Location]
               ,[ErrorCode]
               ,[ErrorDescription]
               ,[Ported]
               ,[PortedFrom]
               ,[PortedFrom2]
               ,[FileRefId]
               ,[CheckDate]
               ,[CreateUserId]
               ,[MSISDN]
               ,[Organisation])

VALUES
               (@ProcessedDataHeaderID,
                @UploadExcelDetailID
               ,@QueryID
               ,@HLRResult
               ,NULL
               ,@MobileCountryISO
               ,@MobileNetworkCode
               ,@MobileNetwork
               ,@NetType
               ,@Location
               ,@ErrorCode
               ,@ErrorDescription
               ,@Ported
               ,@PortedFrom
               ,@PortedFrom2
               ,@FileRefId
               ,@CheckDate
               ,@CreateUserId
               ,@MSISDN
               ,@Organisation);

END

ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[HLRProcessTableFilled] ON [dbo].[tbl_CRM_TempResult]
AFTER INSERT
AS
    --DECLARE @TaskID INT = 0

-- DECLARE @i INT = 1

-- DECLARE @count INT

 DECLARE @TempResultID int
 DECLARE @HLRResult varchar(max)
 DECLARE @QueryID VARCHAR(max)


SET @HLRResult = '';
SET @QueryID = '';




IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT QueryID 
              FROM [WebReg].[dbo].[tbl_HLR_ProcessedData]
              WHERE QueryID = @QueryID)



DECLARE @ProcessedDataHeaderID int
DECLARE @UploadExcelDetailID int
DECLARE @Status varchar(100)
DECLARE @MobileCountry varchar(75)
DECLARE @MobileCountryISO varchar(50)
DECLARE @MobileNetwork varchar(100)
DECLARE @NetType varchar(50)
DECLARE @MobileNetworkCode varchar(50)
DECLARE @Location varchar(50)
DECLARE @ErrorCode varchar(10)
DECLARE @ErrorDescription varchar(100)
DECLARE @Ported bit
DECLARE @PortedFrom varchar(100)
DECLARE @PortedFrom2 varchar(100)
DECLARE @FileRefId int
DECLARE @CheckDate datetime
DECLARE @CreateUserId int
DECLARE @MSISDN varchar(20)
DECLARE @Organisation varchar(1000)


BEGIN
                INSERT INTO [WebReg].[dbo].[tbl_HLR_ProcessedData]
               ([ProcessedDataHeaderID],
                [UploadExcelDetailID]      
               ,[QueryID]
               ,[HlrStatus]
               ,[MobileCountry]
               ,[MobileCountryISO]
               ,[MobileNetworkCode]
               ,[MobileNetwork]
               ,[NetType]
               ,[Location]
               ,[ErrorCode]
               ,[ErrorDescription]
               ,[Ported]
               ,[PortedFrom]
               ,[PortedFrom2]
               ,[FileRefId]
               ,[CheckDate]
               ,[CreateUserId]
               ,[MSISDN]
               ,[Organisation])

VALUES
               (@ProcessedDataHeaderID,
                @UploadExcelDetailID
               ,@QueryID
               ,@HLRResult
               ,NULL
               ,@MobileCountryISO
               ,@MobileNetworkCode
               ,@MobileNetwork
               ,@NetType
               ,@Location
               ,@ErrorCode
               ,@ErrorDescription
               ,@Ported
               ,@PortedFrom
               ,@PortedFrom2
               ,@FileRefId
               ,@CheckDate
               ,@CreateUserId
               ,@MSISDN
               ,@Organisation);


END
```

*Only I don't know how to call the func_Split function's Element value from SP so I can fill the tbl_HLR_ProcessData tables's column values.I'm really sorry about my huge question, Can anybody help me out plz? Any help will appreciated.*

Comment: I removed the mysql tag because the question is clearly about SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

i don't really understand what you are doing. But, your table function returns rows, your trigger will process 1 or more rows at once since sql server calls it once per statement. so your attempt to process just one record is wrong.

what you could do is:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.funcSplit
      ( @DelimitedString  varchar(8000)
      , @Searchword       varchar(20) = ' ' 
      ) 
  RETURNS TABLE
  AS
  RETURN 
  ( select sw, p2.ps, p2.pe, ss
    from ( values (@DelimitedString, @Searchword) ) v (d, sw)
    outer apply ( 
      -- find index of search word in DelimitedString 
      select ps = charindex(sw, d, 1)
      ) p1
    outer apply ( 
      -- find value with searching for first '=' and '&' after searchword 
      select pe = charindex('&', d, p1.ps)
           , ps = charindex('=', d, p1.ps) + 1 
           , l  = len(sw)
      ) p2  
    outer apply ( 
      -- find value with searching for first '=' and '&' after searchword 
      select ss = substring(d, p2.ps, p2.pe - p2.ps)
      -- make sure the found searchword is indeed the whole word and ands with =
      where p1.ps + l + 1 = p2.ps 
        and p2.pe > 0
      union all
            -- find value with searching for first '=' and '&' after searchword 
      select ss = substring(d, p2.ps, len(d) - p2.ps)
      -- make sure the found searchword is indeed the whole word and ands with =
      where p1.ps + l + 1 = p2.ps 
        and p2.pe = 0
      ) ss
  );
```

within your trigger you'll call

```
INSERT INTO [WebReg].[dbo].[tbl_HLR_ProcessedData]
( ...
, QueryID
, ...
, MobileNetworkCode
, ...
)    
SELECT ... 
, sw1.ss
, ...
, sw2.ss
, ...
from inserted i
outer apply ( select * from dbo.funcSplit(i.d, 'QueryID') ) sw1
outer apply ( select * from dbo.funcSplit(i.d, 'NetworkCode') ) sw2
```

you^ll have to replace `i.d` with the columnname of the string to split.

Comment: I tried using outer apply but sql server gives a error,It doesn't identify 'd' in outer apply

Comment: i dont know whats the name of your `DelimitedString` in inserted.

Comment: After calling 'funcSplit() function within trigger 'HLRProcessTableFilled' it got  executed successfully but when I insert some record to the table tbl_CRM_TempResult this gives this error message: Inavalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function. How to fix this error in the funcsplit() function? any help

Comment: @user2510942 corrected the mistake in the split function, there is no '&' at the end of your delimted string. (at least thats the bug i found, if there other, i'll help if you provide some testdata)

Comment: Yes, Your right string doesn't end with '&' operator. here are some test data:

Comment: 'CountryName=Sri+Lanka&Status=Success&QueryID=2294522444&NetworkCode=41303&Organisation=ETISALAT+Lanka+(Private)+Limited+&MSISDN=94720451145&NetworkType=GSM+900%2f1800&Ported=No&Location=947200+LKA&AccountID=1267&NetworkName=ETISALAT&CountryCode=LK'

Comment: 'CountryName=UK&Status=Success&QueryID=232920038&NetworkCode=23430&Organisation=T-Mobile+EE+Limited&MSISDN=447958592938&NetworkType=GSM+1800&Ported=No&AccountID=1267&NetworkName=EE+T-Mobile+&CountryCode=GBR'

Comment: [fiddle] (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/dd525/10) run your example with the searchword provided and a few which cant be found and cant find any problem. you're sure you use the current version? i changed the code after you rightfully complained

Comment: Yeah, It should work but when I call the function within my trigger it doesn't. I replaced the function with your new function. Now when I enter string to the tbl_CRM_TempResult only the primary key of tbl_HLR_ProcessedData get incremented other columns doesn't get filled they remain empty, This is how I called the function. –